# Irssi - how to set text color permanently or in config?

Tags: irc, irssi

Sorry for lame question, but I can't find answer anywhere. I'm using Irssi (on Linux via Putty) and when I want to write something in color, I always input ctrl+c and color number before text. Every each time. Yeah, it's not efficient, so I started searching place, where I could put that color prefix in config file. But I didn't found any placeholder in config file or information on internet where to put it. So, does anybody knows how can I set permanently color for text I'm typing?

Comment: 1) Always writing in color on IRC? That sounds super obnoxious. 2) I don't see how this is a programming question.

Comment: Assuming that a channel isn't already mode +c or similar (strip color), overusing color is a good way to catch a ban or mute in most channels. Regardless, this is off topic and would probably fit better on SuperUser.